# Cannot save text with double quotes in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, textarea

I have this text. . .

> "I got them from the Wicked Witch of the East, when my house fell on her and killed her," she replied.
>
> "Where did you get the mark upon your forehead?" continued the voice.
>
> "That is where the Good Witch of the North kissed me when she bade me good-bye and sent me to you," said the girl.
>
> Again the eyes looked at her sharply, and they saw she was telling the truth.  Then Oz asked, "What do you wish me to do?"
>
> "Send me back to Kansas, where my Aunt Em and Uncle Henry are," she answered earnestly.  "I don't like your country, although it is so beautiful.  And I am sure Aunt Em will be dreadfully worried over my being away so long."

. . . which is placed on a textarea. But after saving it, this is the only part that is saved.

> Send me back to Kansas, where my Aunt Em and Uncle Henry are," she answered earnestly. "I don’t like your country, although it is so beautiful. And I am sure Aunt Em will be dreadfully worried over my being away so long.

This is the POST trace while saving it. . .

```
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "blog"=>{"author"=>"anonymous", "body"=>"Send me back to Kansas, where my Aunt Em and Uncle Henry are,\" she answered earnestly.  \"I don't like your country, although it is so beautiful.  And I am sure Aunt Em will be dreadfully worried over my being away so long.", "title"=>"The Wizard of Oz", "email"=>"anonymous@email.com"}, "authenticity_token"=>"yMkgvsUX2wBjw2EMnbBBMEtGlCUaMcRPN/lyIhxEQ0Y=", "id"=>"3"}
```

I tried escaping the double quotes but still has this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Edited:
Here's the form . . .

```
<% form_for(@blog) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :author %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', blogs_path %>
```

Comment: could you post you form?  Are you escaping by hand?  I find it suspicious that the first and last quotes aren't escaped.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I think I'm having a similar problem where double quotes in a text input are getting truncated.

Answer (score 0):

This is odd.  There are two things I would investigate:  1) Your actual database model.  What is the data type of :body ? Can you post your migration that created the table?  2) I am wondering if an .html_safe would help at all.